# How to generate a SEO URL for a new category in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Adding a new category to the tree in Shopware 6.*5.7.3*,
then activating it has **SEO URLs** in the SEO tab for it showing

`There are no SEO URLs available yet.`

Refreshing the index by admin or in console by `console dal:refresh:index` does not reveal any SEO URL being created in the admin, nor the `seo_url` table.

1. So what exactly will trigger the SEO URLs being generated?
2. If they are now automatically generated at first (when did this change?), wherefrom are they initially being generated?

Updating indices from admin / system / caches & indices did not help.

Updating indices in cli by running `console dal:refresh:index` did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Running `dal:refresh:index` should update it. I suggest using `dal:refresh:index --use-queue` instead, because then it will distribute the tasks to your `messenger:consume` workers and it should finish faster.

You can also check in the `SEO_URL` database table to see if something might be stuck there. E.g. remove the URLs associated with the given category and try running `dal:refresh:index` again. In principle, you could just do a `truncate seo_url;` query and re-generate your seo urls, but in practice you might not want to do that, as you will also loose your redirects. Etc.

Also make sure you have selected the right language in your backend, as having the wrong language selected will just show the wrong SEO URL, and indeed, it might not even exist if a translation is not done for selected language. Various naming conflicts can also results in URLs not being generated properly. E.g. If two product variants accidentally ends up with the exact same URL. This can happen if a variant has a plus sign in its name for instance (it will be stripped), so also make sure there is no naming conflicts with other categories.

Comment: Thank you Jacob. While I did not truncate the table, I tried removing affected entries ... without success.

Comment: As of now it seems a bug with new pages created at root level of the category tree.
When moving them into an existing category - and saving anew - the SEO URL gets created. However, it is being removed as soon as the page is moved back to the root.

Comment: That said, as a side note, from a product claiming itself "mature" ... 
I'd expect same "SEO" URLs not to happen, special chars which are auto-stripped being highlighted in a user-friendly UI, ditto naming conflicts with other and language selection in the backend not to matter or being programmatically claimed "wrong".

Comment: It's possible it could be a bug. I am still on a lower 6.5 version. Maybe try latest version in Dockware and see if you can reproduce; if so, open a bug report about it. And yes, I tend to agree, lot's of things in Shopware is not ready for production, but it is still better than proprietary alternatives, because at least you can fix it when something breaks. Etc.

Comment: Already reported a bug.

Yet here we are again ... 15k of open bugs alone ... the oldest one already older than 4 years. An endless pile that is unlikely to be targeted at in Schöppingen.

Long story short: looking for help where to actually expect it.
So I will keep this issue open and see what we get with 6.6. or another helping hand in here.

So long 

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in a Dockware setup with 6.5.7.3, so this is probably something specific to your environment. Are you sure you remembered to mark the Category as active? (It's a switch in the SEO tab)

Comment: "active" is a switchbox inside the common tab and can the issue be reproduced in a blank community edition.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I suspect crashed workers could also be a cause of this issue. E.g. If the workers are not running, or if they are busy doing something else, it may not be able to update the SEO URL in a timely fashion. Resetting the queue and manually running `messenger:consume -vvv` should confirm or reject this.

Comment: Not yet and the issue is still in with 6.5.8.6. The queues are all set up as background services w/ systemd. The services and queues are running and consuming. Still clueless... ‍♂️